# Filter entries in GraphQL

Tags: query, graphql

I'm using Craft with Gatsby. I'd like to query a featuredpost, and filter that in my entries.

I'm getting the featuredPost slug in gatsby-node, and passing that to createPage, to send a variable to my index template.

In the index template, I want to to filter my entries and remove that slug.